# Can Google Earth be used to display underground 3D structures?

Tags: 3d, google

Trying to make it easy for a non-GIS savy person to view the 3D data I produced in ArcScene. I can't seem to get Google Earth to view underground/below the standard imagery.

Comment: Google earth can't display subsurface data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

Here is a video of heat index from Texas geothermal BHT using Google Earth view below the surface: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeYyJIXOo6Y

You can also access the KML or KMZ files here: 
http://hitechmex.org/kml_examples/. This link also has examples in Cesium using KMZ.

This paper title includes two examples (earthquakes and geothermal) of subsurface in Google Earth: "Geological and hydrological visualization models for Digital Earth representation"

Comment: Now to find this paper explaining how to do this...not for $20. Thanks for the info. this is what im looking for.

Comment: This a recent publication. The publisher provided free access until Aug. 6, 2016. After this date the publisher will charge. Here is the link: [link](http://authors.elsevier.com/a/1TDh3MMTPPHd5)

Comment: Doesn't look like subsurface,to me, looks like it's projecting above the surface.

Comment: GE does not allow going below ground. We changed representation of the surface by extending the surface. The original surface was hidden. A new surface was set at 750Km above the original GE surface. We created navigation ques at different depths. The new surface was set as translucent. A texture was also set at depths about half way and included vector outlines of countries below the new surface. All textures and vectors were added to help the user orientation and were put into separate layers. More information can be found in the paper in previous post. Hope this helps explain the subsurface